# Python: Iterate through Dictionary Values and outPut the Key

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, iteration

The goal is to **match a value given**, in this example **'po'**, to the *values **in** the dictionary* then **output the Key** assigned to that value.

When I run the following I get the output of; None

```
theDict = {'cereal': ['as', '1w', '45'],
           'pop': ['gh', 'er', '65'],
           'crackle': ['yu', 'po', '22']}

for key, value in theDict.items():
    if value == 'po':
        print(key)
```

I am figuring it is only checking the 0 position in each Key.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: replace `if value == 'po':` with `if 'po' in value:`

Comment: Your time and information is appreciated.  This worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually not checking the 0 position of each key. It's comparing the entire value, which is a list/tuple, e.g. (['as', '1w', '45'] == 'po'). If you need to assign the exactly match location, you can do (may be not the best approach):

```
theDict = {'cereal': ['as', '1w', '45'],
       'pop': ['gh', 'er', '65'],
       'crackle': ['yu', 'po', '22']}

for key, values in theDict.items():
    for value in values:
        if value == 'po':
            print(key)
```

If you just need to know if the item is inside of the values for specific key, @alfasin comment solve it for you:

```
theDict = {'cereal': ['as', '1w', '45'],
           'pop': ['gh', 'er', '65'],
           'crackle': ['yu', 'po', '22']}

for key, value in theDict.items():
    if 'po' in value:
        print(key)
```